# Rust: Looping over every file in a directory, collecting and modifying filenames and metadata

Tags: rust

I'm building a simple blog with Axum and Rust, mainly to practice Rust. I find myself finding working solutions to the things I want to do, but I don't like the end result of my code, it doesn't feel right, too many unwraps and too many "if let Ok"s". I'm sure there are more idiomatic ways of achieving what I'm trying to do.

Here I'm looping over a directory, getting the stem of every filename, replacing - with space, and also getting the created metadata and turning it from system time to UTC, then collecting it into a struct, and turning it to JSON to send it off to the client.
I am also sending the actual name of the blog post to the client, to use as a link to the blog post later.

```rust
use std::{fs, path::Path};

use axum::Json;
use chrono::prelude::{DateTime, Utc};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{json, Value};

use crate::error;
use error::Result;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
struct BlogPosts {
    title: String,
    date: String,
    link: String,
}

pub async fn get_blog_posts() -> Result<Json<Value>> {
    let results = blog_posts_title_date();

    let body: Json<Value> = Json(json!(results));

    Ok(body)
}

fn blog_posts_title_date() -> Vec<BlogPosts> {
    let path_to_dir = Path::new("./blog_posts");
    let mut results = vec![];
    if let Ok(entries) = fs::read_dir(path_to_dir) {
        for entry in entries {
            if let Ok(entry) = entry {
                let title = entry
                    .path()
                    .file_stem()
                    .unwrap()
                    .to_str()
                    .unwrap()
                    .to_string();
                let create_time = entry.metadata().unwrap().created().unwrap();
                let date: DateTime<Utc> = create_time.clone().into();
                results.push(BlogPosts {
                    title: title.replace("-", " "),
                    date: format!("{}", date.format("%d-%m-%Y")),
                    link: format!("{}", title),
                })
            }
        }
    }

    results
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn get_files_from_blog_folder() {
        let blog_posts = blog_posts_title_date();

        assert_eq!(
            blog_posts,
            vec![BlogPosts {
                title: "This Is A Test".to_string(),
                date: "30-04-2023".to_string(),
                link: "This-Is-A-Test".to_string(),
            }]
        )

    }
}
```

**Edit:**

After spending the day learning, thinking, and trying. I did come up with a better and cleaner solution. I'm still not 100% happy, but this does handle errors better, now I will return a 404 if no files are found in the folder.
I feel like it could be better, so any feedback would be much appreciated.

**Refactored code:**

````rust
use std::{fs, path::Path};

use axum::Json;
use chrono::prelude::{DateTime, Utc};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{json, Value};

use crate::error::{self, Error};
use error::Result;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
struct BlogPosts {
    title: String,
    date: String,
    link: String,
}

pub async fn get_blog_posts() -> Result<Json<Value>> {
    let results = blog_posts_title_date();


    if let Some(body) = results {
        Ok(Json(json!(body)))
    } else {
        Err(Error::FileNotFound)
    }
}

fn blog_posts_title_date() -> Option<Vec<BlogPosts>> {
    let path_to_dir = Path::new("./blog_posts");
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    let entries = match fs::read_dir(path_to_dir) {
        Ok(entries) => entries,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            return None;
        }
    };

    for entry in entries {
        match entry {
            Ok(entry) => {
                let title = entry.path().file_stem()?.to_str()?.to_string();
                let create_time = entry.metadata().ok()?.created().ok()?;
                let date: DateTime<Utc> = create_time.clone().into();

                results.push(BlogPosts {
                    title: title.replace("-", " "),
                    date: format!("{}", date.format("%d-%m-%Y")),
                    link: format!("{}", title),
                })
            }

            Err(e) => {
                eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
                return None;
            }
        }
    }

    if results.is_empty() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(results)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn get_files_from_blog_folder() {
        let blog_posts = blog_posts_title_date();

        assert_eq!(
            blog_posts,
            Some(vec![BlogPosts {
                title: "This Is A Test".to_string(),
                date: "30-04-2023".to_string(),
                link: "This-Is-A-Test".to_string(),
            }])
        )
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You Want Railway-Oriented Programming

Your instincts were completely correct: there is a better way than writing `.unwrap()` everywhere and panicking on any error.  What you want to do is chain your results together in a way that short-circuits if there are any errors, or returns a result only if there are no errors.

Scott Wlaschin [coined the term “railway-oriented programming” in 2013](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/), comparing it to parallel railway tracks, where a train starts on the main track but there are multiple bypasses that can send it to the other track instead.

[image: Scott Wlascin’s original example.]

So, how do you do this in Rust?  Functions that could fail normally use one of two types from the standard library, usually `Result` (`Ok (x)` or `Err (e)`,  but sometimes `Option` (`Some(x)` or `None`).

You normally use `map` to apply a function that does no error checking to the chain, and `and_then` to apply a function that could return the same type of error.  There are several other options.  (For example, some built-in helpers to convert between  `Option` and `Result`.)  In two places, I apply a closure instead of a function, to deal with a type conversion.

The downside of doing things this way is that the type inference isn’t there yet, so you have to get extremely verbose about your types.  Rust won’t (as of 2023) accept `.map(to_string)` where `self` is a `&str`.  You must specify `.map(str::to_string)`.  To pass an owned value to a function that borrows it, I ended up putting the borrow inside a closure.

### An Example

Here is one of your functions, which contains both a chain of `Option` instances (`title`) and a chain of `Result` instances (`date`), rewritten in a railway-oriented style.  **This code is untested.**

```rust
use chrono::prelude::{DateTime, Utc};
use std::{ffi::OsStr, fs, fs::DirEntry, path::Path};

#[derive(Debug, /* Serialize, Deserialize, */ PartialEq)]
struct BlogPosts {
    title: String,
    date: String,
    link: String,
}

fn blog_posts_title_date() -> Vec<BlogPosts> {
    fn per_entry(entry: DirEntry) -> BlogPosts {
        // The compiler doesn’t need to be told the types of title or date.
        let title: String = entry    // : DirEntry
            .path()                  // : PathBuf
            .file_stem()             // : Option<&OsStr>
            .and_then(OsStr::to_str) // : Option<&str>
            .map(str::to_string)     // : Option<String>
            .unwrap_or_default();    // : String

        let date: DateTime<Utc> = entry       // : DirEntry
            .metadata()                       // : Result<Metadata>
            .and_then(move |md| md.created()) // : Result<SystemTime>
            .map(DateTime::<Utc>::from)       // : Result<DateTime<Utc>>
            .expect("Invalid file metadata.");

        BlogPosts {
            title: title.replace("-", " "),
            date: format!("{}", date.format("%d-%m-%Y")),
            link: format!("{}", title),
        }
    }

    let path_to_dir = Path::new("./blog_posts");
    /* fs::read_dir returns a Result<ReadDir>, where the wrapped ReadDir is an
     * iterator yielding io::Result<DirEntry>.
     */
    fs::read_dir(path_to_dir)
        .expect("Directory ./blog_posts not found.")
        .map(move |x| x.expect("I/O error reading directory entry."))
        .map(per_entry)
        .collect()
}
```

This is a nice example because it requires every combination of `Option`/`Result` and `map`/`and_then`.  So, for the snippet,

```
            .file_stem()             // : Option<&OsStr>
            .and_then(OsStr::to_str) // : Option<&str>
            .map(str::to_string)     // : Option<String>
```

The [`OsStr::to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_str) function could return `None`, so it needs to be chained with `and_then`.  On the other hand, [`str::to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_string) always succeeds, so chain it with `map`.

There’s another use of `map` below that’s different, but not really.  I changed the `for` loop over the `ReadDir` iterator to a `map` followed by `collect`, moving the loop body into a helper function.  These are in fact the same: `map` applies a function to every element of a collection, and treats an `Option` or `Result` as a collection that could be empty or have a single element.  This terminology comes from functional programming.  Haskell is the language that goes furthest in generalizing it in the most abstract way it can.

There are at least two changes in behavior: I had a failure to retrieve the file stem return an empty `String` instead of panicking, but checked the directory entries with `expect` rather than ignoring errors silently.  If you want to go back to ignoring those, change the line

```
    .map(move|x| {x.expect("I/O error reading directory entry.")})
```

to

```
    .filter(Result::is_ok)
    .map(Result::unwrap)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is absolutely amazing, i've learned so much from your code review. I'll definitely make these changes, and spend time to really understanding it.
Thank you for the link to the railway-oriented programming, that will be a good read.
Again, thank you for spending time, really appreciate it.

Comment: @EBjor Thanks! That’s great to hear. I guess I’ll also say that the approach doesn’t make a huge difference in this example, where the program just short-circuits to a panic anyway. But it does if you actually handle errors. For example, if you wanted to search three possible paths until you find one that works, you might write `fs::readdir(paths[0]).or_else(|_| fs::readdir(paths[1]).or_else(|_| fs::readdir(paths[2]))`, and then chain the rest of the computation to that.

Comment: aah! That's a very useful use case for this approach. This was a great help to see where and how I can use more idiomatic Rust. Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you encounter a possible error you have to decide what to do if it happens: do you abort the whole function and send it up the stack? Or do you print it to the console and continue as if nothing happened, maybe substituting with some default value? Or do you abort the program (panic) because if that happens something is very wrong?

Let me show how I would write your function, using the `anyhow` crate:

```
use std::{fs, path::Path};
use chrono::prelude::{DateTime, Utc};
use anyhow::{anyhow, Result, Context};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct BlogPosts {
    title: String,
    date: String,
    link: String,
}

fn blog_posts_title_date() -> Result<Vec<BlogPosts>> {
    let path_to_dir = Path::new("./blog_posts");

    let entries = fs::read_dir(path_to_dir)
        .with_context(|| anyhow!("reading path {}", path_to_dir.display()))?;

    let mut results = Vec::new();
    for entry in entries {
        let entry = entry?;
        
        let Some(title) = entry
            .path()
            .file_stem()
            .map(|s| s.to_string_lossy().into_owned()) else {
                continue;
            };
        let date: DateTime<Utc> = entry
            .metadata()
            .and_then(|m| m.created())
            .with_context(|| anyhow!("getting metadata for file {}", entry.path().display()))?
            .into();

        results.push(BlogPosts {
            title: title.replace("-", " "),
            date: format!("{}", date.format("%d-%m-%Y")),
            link: format!("{}", title),
        })
    }
    Ok(results)
}
```

I've changed the return type to `Result<Vec<BlogPost>>`, the error will not be printed to the console, let the user deal with it. Also note that an empty `Vec` is a perfectly valid value to return.

Then, what to do if the `read_dir()` fails? Just return the error, with the `?` operator. I'm using the `anyhow::with_context` to add details to the error.

The next error point is in reading the entries. That should generally not fail, so just I'm just passing the error up without even bothering adding a context.

Then the title, it can fail with two cases:

1. there is no stem.
2. it could contain a byte sequence that is not a valid string.

I'm checking the the first one with an `if Some(title) = ... else { continue; }` so that invalid files are just ignored. Think for example of the file entries `.git` or `..`: you do not want the function to fail because of that, just ignore this particular entry.

About the second case, I'm using `to_string_lossy` to approximate the file name to a string. That is usually good enough unless you want to go back to the file. If you want to do that, maybe with the `link` field, you should either ignore files with invalid names or keep the `PathBuf` instead of an `String`.

The date of the fail can fail for two different reasons; I'm joining them into one single error with `Result::and_then`.

Finally if the data is good enough the data is added to the resulting vector and this vector is returned.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I'm learning so much from these code reviews. 
I like anyhow crate, it seems like an excellent way to handle errors easily. 
Thank you for your time, really appreciate it.